# Error during mysql workbench installation

Tags: 14.04, mysql-workbench

I try install mysql workbench from deb-package, but its raise error

```
    sudo dpkg -i mysql-workbench-community-6.3.9-1ubuntu16.10-amd64.deb

        selection of the previously unselected mysql-workbench-community package.
    (Reading the database ... at the moment there are 226282 files and a directory installed.)
    Preparing for unpacking mysql-workbench-community-6.3.9-1ubuntu16.10-amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking mysql-workbench-community (6.3.9-1ubuntu16.10) ...
    dpkg: package dependencies do not allow you to configure the mysql-workbench-community package:
    mysql-workbench-community depends on libglibmm-2.4-1v5 (> = 2.48.0), however:
    The version of libglibmm-2.4-1v5: amd64 in the system is 2.46.3-1.
    mysql-workbench-community depends on libgtk-3-0 (> = 3.19.12), however:
    The version of libgtk-3-0: amd64 in the system is 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.2.
    mysql-workbench-community depends on libgtkmm-3.0-1v5 (> = 3.20.0), however:
    The version of libgtkmm-3.0-1v5: amd64 in the system is 3.18.0-1.
    mysql-workbench-community depends on libpangomm-1.4-1v5 (> = 2.40.0), however:
    The version of libpangomm-1.4-1v5: amd64 in the system is 2.38.1-1.
    mysql-workbench-community depends on libpcrecpp0v5 (> = 7.7), however:
    The libpcrecpp0v5 package is not installed.
    mysql-workbench-community depends on libpng16-16 (> = 1.6.2-1), however:
    The libpng16-16 package is not
    dpkg: error when processing the mysql-workbench-community (--install) package:
    dependency problems - leave unconfigured
    Triggers are being processed for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
    Triggers are handled for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
    Triggers are handled for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
    Triggers are being processed for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
    Unknown media type in type 'all / all'
    Unknown media type in type 'all / allfiles'
    The following errors occurred while processing the following packages:
    mysql-workbench-community
```

`sudo apt-get -f install`

```
    Reading Package Lists ... Done
    Building a Dependency Tree
    Reading status information ... Done
    Correcting dependencies ... Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
    Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 1
    Investigating (0) mysql-workbench-community [amd64] <6.3.9-1ubuntu16.10> (utils)
    Broken mysql-workbench-community: amd64 Depends on on libglibmm-2.4-1v5 [amd64] <2.46.3-1> (libs) (> = 2.48.0)
      Removing mysql-workbench-community: amd64 because I can not find libglibmm-2.4-1v5: amd64
    Done
     Done
    Starting pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
    Starting 2 pkgProblemResolver with broken count: 0
    Done
    The following package was installed automatically and is no longer required:
      libpng16-16
    To remove it, use "sudo apt autoremove".
    The following additional packages will be installed:
      libpng16-16
    Packages that will be DELETED:
      mysql-workbench-community
    NEW packages to be installed:
      libpng16-16
    updated 0, installed 1 new package, 1 package was removed for deletion, and 346 packages were not updated.
    not installed to the end or removed 1 package.
    It is necessary to download 0 B / 172 kB archives.
    After this operation, the amount of occupied disk space will be reduced by 168 MB.
    Do you want to continue? [D / N]
    (Reading the database ... at the moment there is 227551 file and directory installed.)
    Mysql-workbench-community (6.3.9-1ubuntu16.10) is removed ...
    Triggers are being processed for shared-mime-info (1.5-2ubuntu0.1) ...
    Unknown media type in type 'all / all'
    Unknown media type in type 'all / allfiles'
    Triggers are handled for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
    Triggers are being processed for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
    Triggers are handled for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
    Selecting the previously unselected package libpng16-16: amd64.
    (Reading the database ... at the moment there are 226282 files and a directory installed.)
    Preparing for unpacking ... / libpng16-16_1.6.20-2_amd64.deb ...
    Unpacking libpng16-16: amd64 (1.6.20-2) ...
    Triggers are being processed for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
    Configures the package libpng16-16: amd64 (1.6.20-2) ...
    Triggers are being processed for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu7) ...
```

Comment: Please show the commands used!

Comment: @George edited question

Comment: nope/  I try this solution

Comment: Ok do `sud dpkg --configure -a`, then `sudo apt-get update` , then  `sudo apt-get install -f`, then `sudo apt-get upgrade`. Please don't use `&&` operator, run each separately

Comment: Please do a translation  of your text before posting it!

Comment: @George add translations